# How to parse JSON response from rest request without name of root element in java

Tags: java, json, rest

I got a response to my request:

```
[
   {
      "data":{
         "channel":{
            "id":"708087644",            
            "__typename":"User"
         }
      },
      "extensions":{
         "durationMilliseconds":112,
         "operationName":"ViewerCardModLogsMessagesBySender",
         "requestID":"01GWVKPD13BQGBZS64TY4824B9"
      }
   }
]
```

I am trying to create a Java class where I can parse this response:

```
ResponseEntity<RestResponse> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, entity, RestResponse.class);
```

However, I still got an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.tomass.twitch.RestResponse` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

`RestResponse` looks like this:

```
public class RestResponse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Root> root = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Root> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(List<Root> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public static class Root {

        private Data data;

        // getters & setters

        public class Data {
            private Channel channel;

            // getters & setters
        }
    }
}
```

When editing the response and the name of the root list then it works: `"{\"root\":`
but I don't know how to parse it without it.

Comment: Your response actually looks like `List<Root>`, not `RestResponse`

Comment: but I can not add generics as return object in postForEntity

Comment: wait a minute, I have a workaround

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to explicitly ask `RestTemplate` to deserialize into `List<Root>`, but you can ask `ObjectMapper`! (if you are using Spring, there is one already available in context) The trick is to store type information into `TypeReference<T>`.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = ...;
    ResponseEntity<String> rawResult = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, entity, String.class);
    List<Root> result = mapper.readValue(rawResult.getBody(), new TypeReference<List<Root>>(){
        /*yes, this is anonymous class*/
    });
```

Comment: ah ok thx so there is no way to cast in postForEntity and I need to return string and then use mapper thx

Answer (score 1):

With **RestTemplate** you could fetch an array of entities and convert it to a list:

```
Root[] rootArray = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Root[].class);
List<Root> roots = Arrays.stream(rootArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you need an unmodifiable list you could use `List.of()` or `Arrays.asList()`.

---

Converting with ObjectMapper you could do a similar thing:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Root[] root = mapper.readValue(myJsonString, Root[].class);
```